# Date Threshold With Psycopg2

Tags: python, date, python-2.7, psycopg2

In the Postgres console I can write...

```
select * from table where date_col < now() - interval '25 days';
```

But how do I do that with Psycopg2?

Running it straight through execute() like this

```
date_bracket = 5
self.cur.execute("""SELECT id FROM bucket WHERE last_crawled <
        now() - interval '%s days'""", (date_bracket, ))
```

Doesn't seem to do anything (no errors, or returned results).

Comment: By running it through `.execute()`? What problems did you run into? What have you tried?

Comment: I've run it through execute(), but nothing happens (no errors from Postgres, no results returned).

Comment: What is `date_bracket`? Is it a string or integer? What happens when you hardcode the value (so not use a parameter at all)?

Comment: date_bracket is an integer, and hardcoding the value has the same result as the substituted value. I've got the block in a try and except clause, so you'd think psycopg2 would be throwing an error.

Comment: Are you 100 certain you are connecting to the same schema? There is *nothing* in there that would indicate that the query somehow should fail otherwise.

Comment: Definitely the same schema, as I have insert statements which are working in other parts of the model (the cursor is shared).

Comment: And a simple `SELECT id FROM bucket` works? What about `SELECT id FROM bucket WHERE last_crawled < 'hardcoded date'`?

Comment: `SELECT id FROM bucket` (in python) doesn't work, although it does in the Postgres console. Could this be due to the number of records (around 500,000)?

Comment: You do know that `cursor.execute()` doesn't return the results straight away, right? You need to then loop over the cursor to fetch rows (you can efficiently loop over 500,000 results that way).

Comment: After you run `self.cur.execute()`, what does `self.cur.fetchone()` give you, for example?

Comment: Yeah, in a conditional — `if self.cur.fetchall():` I log `self.cur.fetchone()`, which has a value of None and I'm also passing the result of `.fetchall()` up the chain.

Comment: That code makes no sense. `fetchall()` fetches *everything*, after which `fetchone()` can no longer get anything at all anymore because you just retrieved all rows with `fetchall()` already.

Comment: I didn't do a good job at explaining that, sorry — http://pastie.org/5786654

Comment: Neither did I it seems; you cannot call `fetchall()` twice. You empty the result set with the first call, the second call will *always* return `None`.

Comment: If you *have* to test for a result before fetching, use the `cursor. rowcount` attribute; `if cursor.rowcount: return cursor.fetchall()`.

Comment: Yeap, that was it! Thanks for your help Martijn, I'd still be stuck if it wasn't for your help.

Answer (score 0):

execute() never returns anything. fetchone(), fetchmany(), fetchall() do. Please read the docs: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html